# Jersey Rest Request Generic type

Tags: java, rest, web-services, generics, jax-rs

I am having the trouble to sent the generic json request from client to server. Here is my service and pojo classes. Can some correct me where i am doing wrong.

Service :

```
@POST
@Path("/executeApp")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}) 
public Response executeApp(Configuration configuration) {

}
```

Config class: This class consist list of Tasks,Task is abstract class is below.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Configuration{


    public Configuration() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public  String udid;    
    public boolean overrideExistingTask;     
    public int repeatPeriodMinutes;

    public List<? extends Task> tasks;
//Getters and setters 

}
```

Task class:

```
public abstract class Task {

    public Task(){

    }
    public String testId; 
    public int pauseSeconds; 
    public int cycles;-

    public abstract String getFriendlyName();

    protected abstract Task<?> getTaskInstance();
    //Getters and setters 

}
```

Derived classes XXXX,YYYYY both extends Task:

```
public class XXXXX extends Task{

    String friendlyName = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    //Extra varibles 

    public XXXXX()  {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyName() {        
        return friendlyName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<?> getTaskInstance() {  
    }
}
```

Client postman request with json:

```
{ 
             "udid":"123", 
             "overrideExistingTask":"true",  
              "repeatPeriodMinutes":"2",
              "tasks":[{"XXXXX":{"testId":"testId", "pauseSeconds" :"5", "cycles":"2" ,"requestId":"123" ,"url":"url", "port":"port" , "udid":"udid" }}]
}
```

error:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.</p>
The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream.
```

If i pass empty array instead of XXXXX, I am able to see the values of Configuration class(udid,overrideExistingTask,repeatPeriodMinutes) in debug mode but taskes values coming []. User can pass list of XXXXX ,YYYYY or both. Can some one suggest me where a doing wrong or missing rest annotation to define generic type.

Comment: "XXXXX"  or YYYY, where is that defined in your schema/bean class?

Comment: Those two bean classes extend from Task Class.

Comment: that is well understood, but how will jaxb know that the bean class too has an attribute with it's class name?

Comment: i don't know that how to specify that.

Comment: @Sri Have you tried putting on the `@XmlRootElement` annotation on your class XXXX & YYYY?

Answer (score 0):

The Configuration object will not be able to parse the provided JSON input.

The tasks fields in the Configuration is  a list of tasks. In the JSON provided, it is a List of Map(/Object) with key "XXXXX" and value is the Task Object.

If this is the JSON to be used, then the tasks field in the Configuration object should be modified to

`public List<Map<String,<? extends Task>> tasks;`

or

The JSON input should be modified to send a list of tasks.

```
{
    "udid": "123",
    "overrideExistingTask": "true",
    "repeatPeriodMinutes": "2",
    "tasks": [{
        "testId": "testId",
        "pauseSeconds": "5",
        "cycles": "2",
        "requestId": "123",
        "url": "url",
        "port": "port",
        "udid": "udid"
    }
//More task objects here
]
}
```